# How to fill all listItems on dropDownList - ASP

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to insert the database of hotels names from the sql,
in each one of the `ListItem`. (trying so much time).

This is the cs code:

```
  <asp:DropDownList id="hotels" runat="server"  >
      <asp:ListItem Text="hotel1"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="hotel2"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="hotel3"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="hotel4"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="hotel5"></asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Text="hotel6"></asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropDownList>
```

and this is the aspx code: which is where I made a huge mistakes.

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string hotel = hotels.Text;// mistake ? or to add ?)
        SqlConnection sqlCon;
        sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ELAD_SSD\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Travels;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand Command;
        Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Hotels.Destiny FROM Travels WHERE Hotel = @hotel", sqlCon);
        Command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("hotel", hotel));

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(Command); 
        adapter.Fill(dt);


        for (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            hotels.Text = dt.Rows.Count;// MISTAKE
        }
    }
}
```

How should I fill each `itemList`?

I know to send it through `Server.Transfer("Hotels.aspx");`

Comment: `hotels.DataSource = dt; hotels.DataBind();`

Answer (score 1):

I assume the listitems are just placeholders? I'd take them out. Then:

```
        foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            hotels.Items.Add(new System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem(dr["Destiny"]));
        }
```

Appologies if this is not 100% correct as I've edited from a working copy. But you get the idea.

Comment: Hi, sorry but it doesn't work, because I don't understand what to change in my own code so it will work as right.   " Items"- ?   "Rows" - error too and the  (dr["Destiny"]) - erorr

Comment: Assuming that your .Fill of the datatable is working, you then need to iterate through the rows that are now in the datatable's rows collection, and for each row add a new listitem to the hotels items collection. The dr["Destiny"] is picking out the column named "Destiny". All this goes in place of your for loop.

Comment: defintly not true and all error, just a huge mistake. there is nothing as "hotels.item" and "dr"   I did:                       
            DataRow r = table.Rows[i];
            Session["1"] = table.Rows[i];
            Session["2"] = table.Rows[i];
            Session["3"] = table.Rows[i];
            Session["4"] = table.Rows[i];
            Session["5"] = table.Rows[i];

Comment: It is with  site navigation (why there is no enter here?) I use    Server.Transfer("Hotels.aspx");   the whole data transtered to Hotels.aspx page